# Designing for full screen

Tags: layout, visual-studio-2019

**Summary:** I'm having a big problem with layout design in my project... I want to set it up in **fullscreen** mode, but I can only set it in a **specify** resolution, because of that, when I click to **maximize** my program, it goes like image #2... I tried to **anchor** buttons in "Top,Left,Bottom,Right" but the mess is bigger (image #3).

**What I need:** I want to make a single layout for a fullscreen mode in **any screen** resolution...

[image: Visual Studio]

Image 1 below
[image: Image 1]

Image 2 below
[image: Image 2]
Image 3 below
[image: Image 3]

When I use fill mode...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right and you want everything to stretch when you resize your form then you should dock your tablelayoutpanel (fill) and the same with your buttons.

Comment: I tried that... Tried to dock them, but when I do that and maximize the window, they go all for an anormal size, with big spaces between them...

Comment: Can you show me what you mean ? I tried to upload a pic to show you how it looks but i dont know how to upload pics here

Comment: Look at the pic number 3... That's what happens when you dock commands and maximize the window....

Comment: Mine expand when i `dock` it in `fill` mode, and anchor the control to 4 sides.

Comment: It doesnt work, when I change 1 command to fill mode, it fills all the screen... I edited my post with the screenshot...